I cannot access MISP dashboard
T-Guard is an open-source unified security solution. I am in the process of installing T-Guard components. After following all the steps in the setup GUI interface (I will attach a picture).

I can access the dashboard of (Wazuh, IRIS, and Shuffle) using the credential information provided in T-Guard documentation (I will attach a picture of the credential information provided in T-Guard documentation).

Still I cannot access MISP dashboard although all the containers are running (I will attach a picture of all the running containers related to MISP).

When I try to access MISP dashboard using (https://:1443), the page freezes.


This is a question best asked of the makers of the app you installed.
